# Maintaining Series Format in Chart: VBA Event for MDX Legend Changes

Tags: excel, vba, mdx, powerpivot

**Is there a solution through VBA or by editing my MDX set, or anything else, to apply my Series formatting and make my measure/series colors consistent, even when isolated?**

Or in other words, when I click "Issued" it shows my "Issued" Series and keeps it blue. If I toggle "Received" it will show "Received", yellow,  and "Issued", still blue.

I've created a Dashboard featuring a Pivot Chart that uses an MDX Legend Set to toggle Measures based on Slicer selection [using the method outline here.](http://excel-inside.pro/blog/2017/04/07/dynamically-select-measures-to-be-shown-on-a-power-bi-visual-via-slicer/)

My measures are variations of this:

```
Issued:=If(CONTAINS(Chart_Filters, Chart_Filters[Chart Filters], "Issued"), [Count_Final_Approval], BLANK())
```

And the MDX Set is:

```
Nonempty({([Measures].[Received]),([Measures].[Processed]),([Measures].[Issued])})
```

Works great.

For a previous Dashboard without MDX sets, I solved the issue of maintaining consistent formatting for chart series using [this method](https://peltiertech.com/vba-conditional-formatting-of-charts-by-series-name/) through Worksheet_Activate () and Worksheet_Calculate ().

All of my other slicers properly implement the formatting VBA, except for the slicer that dictates which measures are featured in my chart [Chart_Filters]. Damn.

I haven't had any luck using the PivotTable VBA events.

I am assuming there is something in the mechanism of MDX that I am missing which is why I can't catch any of the changes to trigger the format code.

If needed, the formatting code is as follows:

```
   On Error Resume Next

  Dim rPatterns As Range
  Dim iSeries As Long
  Dim rSeries As Range
  Dim icategory As Long
  Dim rcategory As Range
  Dim vcategories As Variant
  Dim Chart As ChartObject

  Set rPatterns = Sheets("Colors").Range("A3:A5")

'Application by Time Chart Formatting 

Set Chart = Sheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects("RBarLicApps")

    Chart.Chart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
        "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\AppsOverTime" _
        )
    Chart.Chart.ShowAllFieldButtons = False
    With Chart.Chart
    For iSeries = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
      Set rSeries = rPatterns.Find(What:=.SeriesCollection(iSeries).Name, _
          LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If Not rSeries Is Nothing Then
        .SeriesCollection(iSeries).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
            rSeries.Interior.Color
      End If
    Next
  End With
```

I've piecemealed everything I know, so please keep this in mind if my methodology is way off base. MDX is brand new to me, although I am willing to push myself if the solution is complex.

Thanks!

Comment: First thing to note, that blanket `On Error Resume Next` at the top is hiding potential errors... you want to get rid of it.

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, done. No errors when tested.